# 2nd order ODE w/o power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

$(1-t^2)\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}-2t\frac{dx}{dt}+6x=0$

And I have the initial conditions as follows:

$x(0)=1, \frac{dx}{dt}=0$

I know power series can be used to solve this ODE, and also know the answer is $x = 1-3t^2$.

Any kind of help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you get using power series ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write a question ...
I want to know whether or not it is possible to solve this ODE without power series.
(I could get correct answer using power series)

Comment: Without these specific conditions, it is not too ugly. It is a Sturm‐Liouville equation. Try with Wolfram Alpha typing **Solve (1 - t^2) x''[t] - 2 t x'[t] + 6 x[t]=0**

Comment: Thank you for quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

Your ODE is Legendre's equation
$$
(1-t^2)\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}-2t\frac{dx}{dt}+\ell (\ell + 1)x=0
$$
with $\ell = 2$ so the solution to that is the Legendre polynomial of degree 2
$$
P_2(t)=\frac{1}{2}(3t^2-1)
$$
This is still a solution when multiplied by a constant. If you multiply by $-2$ it satisfies your initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
As I got the name of this type of ODE, I could find solution process on the internet.
I'll trace the process.
Thank you again!

Comment: It is a 'standard' ODE with well known and understood analytic solutions, hence if you recognise it as Legendre's eqn. then you do not need the power series. Yes there are lots of internet resources discussing this.